# type 'Future<DateTime>' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, futuretask

In my Flutter app I'm fetching some datetime info from an API but getting this error. I'm using Provider.

My display widget has this in didChangeDependencies:

```
_userDateTime = Provider.of<TimeZones>(context, listen: false).getDateTime(0);
print('didChangeDependencies()');
print(_localDateTime.toString());
print(DateFormat("E d MMM hh:mm a").format(_localDateTime));
```

and this outputs ok up until I try to use that datetime object.

```
flutter: didChangeDependencies()
flutter: Instance of 'Future<DateTime>'

======== Exception caught by widgets library
```

So I know that TimeZones is returning a DateTime object, I can test the values and see that it's right.

How do I get my widget to accept the Future and treat it as a normal DateTime?

or is there a better approach?

Comment: as you used `Future` method to get date time it's not type of dateTime. So, you just need to use `async` to me method and `await` to that `_userDateTime` like `_userDateTime = await Provider.of<TimeZones>(context, listen: false).getDateTime(0);`. And your problem is solved.!

Answer (score 1):

Add async to the didChangeDependencies function and await for the getDatetime result like this:

```
_userDateTime = await Provider.of<TimeZones>(context, listen: false).getDateTime(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I hadn't added a .then() check, and I split the set and get functionality out and it's much, much happier!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `getDateTime(0)` call returns a future.
Try to await it:

`_userDateTime = await Provider.of<TimeZones>(context, listen: false).getDateTime(0);`

Answer (score 0):

In didChangeDependencies I changed the provider request to

```
Provider.of<TimeZones>(context, listen: false)
          .setDateTime(-1, 0)
          .then((_)
```

and in my builder I call

```
final tzData = Provider.of<TimeZones>(context);
    DateTime _localDateTime = tzData.getDateTime(-1);
    DateTime _userDateTime = tzData.getDateTime(0);
```

and it seems to work as expected. More testing needed.